# JMeter:Higher response times with JDBC sampler

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

I have created a test plan to stress test out MySQL DB. The test plan executes without errors, but the response times for JMeter are pretty much higher than when i actually execute query manually. With JMeter average response times are about 500 ms. While for the same query it takes 0.00 sec when run manually from console.

I am using JDBC samplers to execute queries which include INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT. Are there any best practice to make DB stress test as close to reality as possible. I was not able to find much on DB stress test with JMeter.

Comment: Are you sure that your console reports correct time? 0.00 sec sounds like its not. it should take at least few mills.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. For some queries it is showing about 0.03. If i change the parameters and run the same query, the time goes down to 0.00. Besides, my PHP application running with the same database has faster response times.

Comment: Can you try different SQL consoles? I wonder if its JDBC driver issue... so example try http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net

Comment: Found out the issue. Needed to adjust Max number of connections in JDBC configuration.

Comment: Great. Then you can answer to your own question below. So others can also benefit for similar issue.